# Replace every sequence of letters with a random word

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I created a list of random words:

```
library(OpenRepGrid)
list_of_words <- randomWords(100)
list_of_words <- gsub("[^A-Za-z ]", "", list_of_words)
list_of_words <- list_of_words[nchar(list_of_words) %in% 4:6]
list_of_words <- list_of_words[!(duplicated(list_of_words)|duplicated(list_of_words, fromLast=TRUE))]
```

And I have a string as follows:

```
dat_string <- "Code bla-group Description bla-groep somecoëfficiënt\nP1 building 0,325\nN2111 veggies 0,387"
```

I would like to replace all sets of consecutive letters (`Code, bla, Description, ...`) with a random word of the `list_of_words`.

I thought of doing:

```
dat_string <- gsub("[:alpha:]",sample(list_of_words),dat_string)
```

But the output is a bit unexpected;

```
"Code bHarryHarry-grouHarry DescriHarrytion bHarryHarry-groeHarry somecoëfficiënt\nP1 buiHarryding 0,325\nN2111 veggies 0,387"
```

Could anyone explain to me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Never use bare POSIX character classes, use `"[[:alpha:]]"`

Comment: Try `library(stringr)` and then `str_replace_all(dat_string, "\\p{L}+", function(x) sample(list_of_words, 1))`

Comment: It'd help if you put the expected output as well

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```r
library(stringr)
str_replace_all(dat_string, "\\p{L}+", function(x) sample(list_of_words, 1))
```

Here, `\p{L}+` matches one or more Unicode letters (thus matching any word) and then the word is replaced by a random element from the `list_of_words` character vector.